# Why Google Appengine Server is taking much time for the first request after a new instance is created?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using GoogleAppengine Java. I would like to know why is it taking much time for the first request when a new instance is created?. I would also like to know are there any best ways to analyse the performance of the Google Appenige application?.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

### High response times for new instances

When the first request causes AppEngine to create a new instance, there are additional tasks involved like loading required libraries, running static initializers, instantiating servlet classes etc.

These can be done prior to have a first requrests served by a new instance. This is why **warmup-requests** were invented. You can tell AppEngine to run some code before an instance is ready to serve requests, eliminating the higher response time for new instances. You can read more about this here:

[**Warmup Requests (Java AppEngine web.xml)**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests)

Also please read about [Setting the Number of Idle Instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Number_of_Idle_Instances) and [Setting the Pending Latency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Pending_Latency).

### Statistics

There is a very detailed, built-in statistics solution for developers. You have to manually enable it though and then it will appear on your admin console. It uses the [Servlet Filter API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to "hook" into all your calls and performs measurements and statistical calculations.

Here are more details on it:

[**Appstats for Java**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats)

Comment: The request is routed to the new instance, when the new instance is ready. (We are already doing expensive intializations in the ServletContextListners and also added the servlets in the load-on-startup in the web.xml). In this new instance, the serving is taking longer (if the same request is served in old instance, then it is faster).  Why is this happening??

Comment: Your Servlet might refer to other classes which might need to be loaded, initialized, instantiated etc.